Is a chordal graph with exactly two simplicial vertices an interval graph?

A chordal graph is one in which all cycles of four or more vertices have a chord.

A graph is called an interval graph if each of its vertices can be associated with an interval on the real line in such a way that two vertices are adjacent if and only if the associated intervals have a nonempty intersection.

A vertex is simplicial if its neighborhood is either empty or a clique.


It is well known that every interval graph is chordal, but the converse is not necessarily true.
Dirac (1961) proved that every chordal graph with at least two vertices has at
least two simplicial vertices.
[1] Dirac, G. A. (1961), On rigid circuit graphs, Abhandlungen aus dem Mathematischen Seminar der Universität Hamburg, （25）71–76, doi:10.1007/BF02992776
I am trying to add some constraints to chordal graphs to make them interval graphs. A starting step is the number of simplicial vertices. I have a vague feeling that the following assertion is correct. But  I haven't come up with a good proof yet.
Problem 1. If a chordal graph with exactly two simplicial vertices, then it is interval graph.
Note that in Problem 1, 2 cannot be increased to 3, as there is a counterexample. It has three simplicial vertices $1,4,6$, and is not interval.


By an "empty" neighborhood do you mean a neighborhood that is the empty set, or a neighborhood that has no edges?

It means a neighborhood that is the empty set.

Yes, it is true. Let $G$ be a chordal graph with two simplicial vertices $u$ and $v$. If $|G| = 2$, then $G \cong K_2$ or $G \cong 2K_1$ is interval graph.
Now suppose that every chordal graph $H$ with two simplicial vertices is interval if $|H| < |G|$ and that there exists a set $S_H$ of intervals together with matching between vertices of $H$ and intervals of $S_H$ such that intervals corresponding to the simplicial vertices of $H$ are the leftmost and the rightmost ones, i. e., contain the leftmost and the rightmost points of union of $S_H$.
Let's remove the simplicial vertex $u$ from graph $G$. Remaining graph $G - u$ is chordal since this property is hereditary. Therefore $G - u$ has at least two simplicial vertices. If it has more than two simplicial vertices then all of them except may be $v$ are adjacent to $u$ in the graph $G$, because every vertex not adjacent to $u$ doesn't change simplicity after deleting $u$. Thus they are adjacent to each other in both graphs $G$ and $G - u$. Then they have the same neighborhood in the graph $G - u$. Let's contract together all simplicial vertices of $G - u$ expect the vertex $v$. The remaining graph $H \subset G$ is chordal and has two simplicial vertices $w$ and $v$ therefore is interval. WLOG $w$ corresponds to the leftmost interval of $S_H$. Duplicating this interval few more times (possibly with some inessential shifting) we get intervals corresponding to the other simplicial vertices of $G - u$. And adding one more interval to the left intersecting only interval corresponding to $w$ and its copies we get an interval corresponding to the vertex $v$ of the graph $G$. Therefore the graph $G$ is interval and there exists corresponding set $S_G$ of intervals.

"And intervals corresponding to the simplicial vertices are leftmost and rightmost." this seems non-trivial to me, is there are an easy argument for why we can assume this?

@BrandonduPreez I also have the same question.

@BrandonduPreez I mean that exists such set of intervals that simplicial vertices correspond to intervals containing the leftmost and the rightmost points of union of all intervals. (However not every possible set has such property.) This statement is proven inductively in my answer

@Smylic So is the statement that intervals corresponding to the simplicial vertices are leftmost and rightmost  also your inductive hypothesis?

@licheng Yes. I have edited my answer to make it more rigorous
